# Malloc a 2D array in C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, malloc

Every time I allocate the memory for a 2D array first I create an array of `int**` and then with a for I allocate the memory for each element.

For example:

```
int ** arr = malloc(N*sizeof(int *));
for(i=0; i< N; i++) arr[i] = malloc(M*sizeof(int));
```

Wouldn't be possible allocate the memory like:

```
int ** arr = malloc(N*sizeof(int[M]));
```

or

```
int ** arr = malloc(sizeof(int[N][M]));
```

in order to avoid the `for`?

Comment: Are you using C or C++?

Comment: You could write your own function containing everything necessary to do that. Other than that there is no syntax trickery that would make it possible.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794202/freaky-way-of-allocating-two-dimensional-array/36799070#36799070).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

like this : `int (*arr)[M] = malloc(sizeof(int[N][M]));`

`arr` is pointer to `int[M]`.

use like `arr[0][M-1];`

and `free(arr);`

Comment: Even better - `int (*arr)[M] = malloc( sizeof *arr * N );`.  This way you don't have to modify the `sizeof` expression if the type of `arr` ever changes.

Comment: @JohnBode see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32985668/971127)

Comment: Obviously that's only an issue if `M` isn't a compile time constant.  And even if it is, "evaluate" doesn't have to be synonymous with "dereference".  All that needs to be "evaluated" is the *type* of the expression `*arr`; there's no logical reason that `sizeof` would ever need to *dereference* `arr` to determine its type.  Yes, if you want to be strictly pendantic (and who among us doesn't), the behavior is undefined, but only because the definition of "evaluate" is imprecise.

Comment: @JohnBode In that post I am a similar opinion with you. However, it should be avoided because it does not find no guarantee of such operations in the standard.

Comment: And then there's this language from 5.1.2.3/4: "In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics. **An
actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its
value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced** (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a volatile object)."  I think this gives us an out for using `sizeof` on a pointer to a VLA.

Comment: @JohnBode I think that very has been matched to our claim (and behavior of gcc). I will remember this. Do you can try to point out to that answer and the post?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY So this doesn't work when M is a variable?

Answer (score 24):

`int ** arr = malloc(N*sizeof(int[M]));`

is incorrect C code, if you simulate it by allocating once
`int *arr = malloc(N*M*sizeof(int));`
and access it by
`arr[i*M + j]`,
this is an analog to `arr[I][j]` in your first case.

Comment: @Olaf Calm down, there is no 2D array you can have with C, the OP want is to allocate once for a buffer to hold NxM ints.

Comment: Plus, it is not at all "obsolete", it is something you see today. It all depends your use case. It's odd you can declare some way of code as "obsolete" after all.

Comment: I just asked if there was a way **like** that, I never said that **that** was the way.

Comment: @fluter: You very well can! See my answer. And yes, it _is_ obsolete. It is just that there are too many programmers who think there are no multi-dimensional arrays in C. But just beause "we did it that way all the time" does not mean it is the correct way. In fact, there is not a single advantage in your version, but a lot against it, e.g.: error-prone, harder to understand, you have to trace the inner-length yourself.

Comment: Oh, and sorry, for the hefty reaction. It is just too much confusion about arrays and pointers. And too many programmers in fear of using complex arrays, although it becomes pretty simple once you understood the concept (things get worse with qualifiers, though).

Comment: @Olaf I agree with you that use a pointer to an array is a good one, and I didn't say the way I used is the only way, it's just one solution. Again, it's a pointer to an array, not a 2D array by nature.

Comment: To recover the ability to use `arr[i][j]` syntax, folow up with casting to `int (*)[M]`. Do `int (*arr)[M] = int (*)[M] malloc(N*M*sizeof(int))`.

Answer (score 11):

You have a "pointer to pointer". That cannot represent a 2D array.

The correct declaration of a pointer to a 2D array is

```
// number of elements in one row
#define COLS 10

// number of rows
#define ROWS 20

int (*array)[COLS];   // mind the parenthesis!
```

That makes `array` a *pointer to array of `COLS` `int`s*. The type is `int (*)[COLS], btw. but you don't need the type, see below.

To allocate the array you should then use the standard allocation for a 1D array:

```
array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * ROWS);   // COLS is in the `sizeof`

array = malloc(sizeof(int[ROWS][COLS])); // explicit 2D array notation
```

Which variant to use is personal style. While the first contains no redundancy (consider you change the declaration of `array` to use `INNER` instead of `COLS` or the element-type to `float`). The second is more clear at a fist glance, but more prone to errors when modifying the declaration of `array`.

To `free`:

```
free(array);
```

Comment: I'd be curious to know what the downvoter's objection was.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Me too. But you cannot argue with <(well, you might have an idea what I would write here)>.

Comment: `array = int (*)[COLS] malloc(ROWS*COLS*sizeof(int))` _may_ be more intutive

Comment: @rfabbri That's less intuitive than the second variant I propose. Additionally the first proposed version also guarantees the inner index to be always consistent to the pointer type. This is not true for the second and your variant. Finally: never typecast ´void *´ in C! This is one of the stupidities of some coding styles. Please note, this is different in C++, but that's a different language not subject here.