# 2D Math Matrix with Malloc

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I know a similar question is already asked here for example:

[Malloc a 2D array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36890624/malloc-a-2d-array-in-c)

However, my question is not how to create one but rather if I should prefer to use for a mathematical 2D matrix a "real" 2D array (with pointers of pointers) or rather a flattened 1-dimensional array with proper indexing.

Comment: From a pure mathematical perspective, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I meant rather from a programming perspective.

Comment: In most cases that doesn't really matter either. For a good answer you need to give us much more details, like what is the assignment or exercise you're tasked with solving? What are its requirements? Its limitations? Please [edit] your question to elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only case it can be important is when you are doing operations that depends on the neighbors of the matrix. In this case, using a 2D matrix is a bit better because it avoids cache misses.

This is specially important for problem solutions that use dynamic programming optimization .

I believe it can also be important for image processing, where many operations are applied in a rectangle of pixels.