# Is it possible to release the 2D array without a for loop?

Tags: arrays, c, free

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* create2dArray(int r,int c) {
    int (*arr)[c] = (int(*)[c])malloc(sizeof(*arr) * r);
    return arr;
}

void release2dArray(void* arr) {
    free(arr);
}

int main() {
    int r = 10, c = 20;
    int (*arr)[c] = (int (*)[c])create2dArray(r, c);
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = i * c + j;
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    release2dArray(arr);
    arr[0][2] = 20;
    printf("%d ", arr[1][2]);
}
```

In the code, I allocate contiguous memory for a 2D array using a pointer to the array. To  release the memory, I want to directly use release2dArray(arr) because I know that the memory allocated information is stored somewhere before the allocated memory itself. I think it should work but it fails. So is it possible for me to release the memory of 2D array without passing the shape of that array into function release2dArray() and without using a for loop?

Comment: You're not creating it correctly. You allocated an array of `r` pointers, but never allocated any memory for the rows. The loop that fills in the array has undefined behavior.

Comment: The allocation / deallocation is fine.  You're attempting to use memory after it's been freed.

Comment: I refered the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36890624/malloc-a-2d-array-in-c. I know that after releasing the memory, I should not use array pointer arr to visit the memory again, which will lead to undefined behavior. However, if releasing is successfully, I think all elements should be 0 except the arr[0][2]. Why only arr[0][0] and arr[0][1] equal 0?  All other elements still keep their original value. If I use pointer to pointer to allocate the memory and use for loop to release the memory, all elements are reset to be 0.

Comment: *"I know that after releasing the memory, I should not use array pointer arr to visit the memory again, which will lead to undefined behavior."*  That's exactly what you're doing on the last two lines, so your program has UB.

Comment: Quote *"I think it should work but it fails"* That is not a good error description! How does it fail?

Comment: @Barmar The allocation seems fine. `arr` is a pointer to an array of `c` ints.

Comment: Quote: *"However, if releasing is successfully, I think all elements should be 0..."* What made you think that? Wher did you read that `free` sets elements to zero?

Comment: @Barmar `int (*arr)[c] = (int(*)[c])malloc(sizeof(*arr) * r);` is not allocating [an array of r pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77212916/is-it-possible-to-release-the-2d-array-without-a-for-loop/77213348#comment136120280_77212916).

Comment: Quote: *" I know that after releasing the memory, I should not use array pointer arr to visit the memory again, which will lead to undefined behavior."* Okay, so why do you do it when you already know you shouldn't?

Comment: Cast to malloc is unnecessary and it causes only noise. And consider returning a pointer to an incomplete array for better type safety. `typeof(int[])* create2dArray(int r,int c) { ... }`. BTW, is there any real need for such alloc/release functions?

Comment: @Barmar he is not allocating pointers. His allocation is OK

Comment: Is the question actually why `arr[0][2] = 20;` crashes after the memory is freed? Because that should be pretty obvious...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "However, if releasing is successfully, I think all elements should be 0 except the arr[0][2]."

No, do not expect that.  After `release2dArray(arr);` there is no defined way to use `arr` with its old value..  Do not attempt to access via the pointer after `free()`, unless it is later assigned allocated memory.

```
    release2dArray(arr);

    // Do not attempt the following code.
    // It is undefined behavior (UB).
    //arr[0][2] = 20;
    //printf("%d ", arr[1][2]);
```

---

> is it possible for me to release the memory of 2D array without passing the shape of that array into function release2dArray() and without using a for loop?

Yes.  This part of OP's code is fine.

```
void release2dArray(void* arr) {
    free(arr);
}

    ... 
    release2dArray(arr); // Just fine
```

---

BTW, OP is allocating well.

- Minor: The cast is not needed.
- Minor: Consider `size_t` for array sizing.  That type is neither too narrow nor too wide.

```
// void* create2dArray(int r, int c) {
void* create2dArray(size_t r, size_t c) {
    // int (*arr)[c] = (int(*)[c])malloc(sizeof(*arr) * r);
    int (*arr)[c] = malloc(sizeof *arr * r);
    return arr;
}
```