# How to allocate the memory for matrices(2DArray) dynamically in which rows and columns are also allocated dynamically?

Tags: c++, c

In my code, it only allocating memory for one matrix. When I try to allocate memory for two matrices here just two columns of memory are allocating and there is no other chance to allocate memory for the second matrix.

Here is my Code

```
    void 2DArray()
     {
         int noOfRows, noOfColumns, noOfMatrices;
         printf("\n\n ENTER THE NUMBER OF  MATRICES YOU WANT TO ADD : ");
         scanf("%d",&noOfMatrices);
         int **2DArray = (int**)malloc((noOfMatrices * sizeof(int)));

         for(int i = 0; i < noOfMatrices; i++)
          {
                  2DArray[i] = (int*)malloc((sizeof(int) * noOfRows));
          }
     }
```

Please help me!

Comment: It is not 2D array. It is array of pointers!!

Comment: @Nagrocks Naa - `noOfRows` and `noOfColumns` are uninitialized - you have to make up your mind where their values shall come from.

Comment: Why are you tagging with C and C++? They are two completely different languages.

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, describe your actual problems (observations, expectations etc.). Lastly, as mentioned above, go through the description of the tags that you applied, the two are mutually exclusive in general.

Answer (score 1):

In C:

```
void *allocate2DintArray(size_t cols, size_t rows)
{
    int (*arr)[rows][cols];
    return malloc(sizeof(*arr));
}
```

In C++ (one of the possible ways)

```
vector <vector <int>> Matrix(rows, vector <int>(cols, 0));
```

Comment: There is a debate if `sizeof(*arr)` is UB or not. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32985424/is-the-operand-of-sizeof-evaluated-with-a-vla?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @tstanisl all known by compilers do it properly - it means that their developers interpret it the different way than SO gurus. For me, compiler developers interpretation is more important than the SO one.