# Does typedef (pointer to) VLA require evaluation of the size expression?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, declaration, typedef, variable-length-array

Does typedef VLA require evaluation of the size expression?

```
int f(void);
int main(void)
{
    typedef int (T) [ f() ];       // is f required to be evaluated ?
    T x;
    return sizeof x;
}
```

Does typedef *pointer to* VLA require evaluation of the size expression?

```
int f(void);
int main(void)
{
    typedef int (*T) [ f() ];      // is f required to be evaluated ?
    T x;
    return sizeof x;
}
```

UPD. In the definition of `f` is visible, then a call to it may be optimized out:

```
int f(void)
{
    return 4;
}

int main(void)
{
    typedef int (*T) [ f() ];
    return sizeof(T);
}
```

Generated code (both GCC and LLVM):

```
main:
        mov     eax, 8
        ret
```

It is expected, because there is no real need to call `f` to determine the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the C Standard ([§6.7.8 Type definitions](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.8))

> 3 In a declaration whose storage-class specifier is typedef, each
> declarator defines an identifier to be a typedef name that denotes the
> type specified for the identifier in the way described in 6.7.6. **Any
> array size expressions associated with variable length array
> declarators are evaluated each time the declaration of the typedef
> name is reached in the order of execution.**

And there is an example in the C Standard

> 8 EXAMPLE 5 If a typedef name denotes a variable length array type,
> the length of the array is fixed at the time the typedef name is
> defined, not each time it is used:

```
void copyt(int n)
{
    typedef int B[n]; // B is n ints, n evaluated now
    n += 1;
    B a; // a is n ints, n without += 1
    int b[n]; // a and b are different sizes
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        a[i-1] = b[i];
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f( void )
{
    static int n;
    
    return ++n;
}

void g( void )
{
    typedef int ( *T )[ f() ];
    
    T p;
    
    printf( "sizeof( *p ) = %zu\n", sizeof( *p ) );
}

int main(void) 
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        g();
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
sizeof( *p ) = 4
sizeof( *p ) = 8
sizeof( *p ) = 12
sizeof( *p ) = 16
sizeof( *p ) = 20
sizeof( *p ) = 24
sizeof( *p ) = 28
sizeof( *p ) = 32
sizeof( *p ) = 36
sizeof( *p ) = 40
```

Comment: The interesting thing here is that, [according to the top answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32985424/10871073), the `sizeof x` expression in OP's code (first snippet, anyway) is undefined behaviour.

Comment: ... possibly. If the *definition* of OP's `f()` is in a separate TU, then their `sizeof` cannot be evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: @AdrianMole: the size of a VLA is evaluated at runtime — not compile time.

Comment: @AdrianMole: The undefined behavior in the post yoiu link is due to dereferencing an uninitialized pointer (even though the value of the uninit pointer is ignored; all that matters is the type).  That does not apply to `sizeof x` (but does to `sizeof *p`)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hmm. I guess I'll need to modify my replies as to how the `sizeof` operator works. I was assuming that a VLA is an "incomplete type" but that's wrong. C11 clearly states that a VLA ***is*** a complete type.